# Hard to breath or difficulty breathing?

Tags: grammar, vocabulary

> My nose is running. I am **hard** to breath through nose.
>
> My nose is running. I have a **difficulty** breathing through nose.

Which is the correct adjective to describe that you have a runny nose.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both could be OK with some editing:

> My nose is running. **It is hard** **to breathe** through **my** nose.
>   My nose is running. I **have/am having** difficulty breathing through **my** nose.

A possessive pronoun is usually used when describing someone's body parts.

As a note: Some people might use *a difficulty*, though I wouldn't.

Comment: What can be the reasons that a possessive pronoun is usually used when describing someone's body parts? I just wonder why. :)

Answer (score 0):

In everyday conversation, I think I'd say it something like this:

> *My nose is running; it's hard for me to breathe through my nose.*

or even:

> *My nose is running; I can't breathe through my nose.*

(In the latter case, "I can't breathe" is being used to mean, "I'm having trouble with breathing" – it doesn't necessarily have the more literal meaning of being unable to breathe through my nose at all. English is tricky like that.)

*Difficulty* is a more formal word that; normally, I'd be less likely to use it except in a more formal context. For example, a doctor might ask a patient:

> *Are you having any difficulty breathing through your nose?*

Answer (score -1):

For me, *difficulty breathing* and *hard to breathe* are too general to capture the just the sense of *My nose is running*. Instead, except perhaps in the most formal contexts, I would simply use *runny*.

> My nose is running. I have a **runny** nose.

Comment: ...Unless you wanted to emphasize that your runny nose was causing breathing problems.